# How can I calculate the transfer function of this system?

Tags: control-system, transfer-function

[image]

I have already calculated P=-5 and Q=-6

Comment: Look like a homework assignment. To get answers hre you need to show us some work first.

Comment: It is a standard control system block diagram reduction problem. A starting point is to move the take-off point from x1 to y. this wil require inserting an s+1 block in cascade with P.

Comment: pinkcat, just solve it like you would any nodal equation. Treat each two-terminal block you see there as a two-terminal device on a schematic. Treat each line with an arrow as a node. For the three-terminal sum/difference devices it is equally trivial. They observe their two inputs and drive their output with a very simple function. The whole thing just falls out using nodal equations. If your teacher absolutely requires that you use some specific method and that you must show your skill with it, such as suggested by RussellH, then do that. But you should know how since you've been trained.

Comment: pinkcat, are you just looking to be given an answer or do you want to know how to develop your own answer? Do you know how KCL/nodal is applied to active+passive and/or passive circuits? Can you solve simultaneous equations?

Comment: In Python/Sympy: `simplify(solve([Eq(u,r*12-(x1*P+y*Q)),Eq(x1,u/(s+1)),Eq(y,x1/(s+1))],[u,x1,y])[y]/r)` yields the result. You really should be able to write these out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reduced the circuit as advised and was able to produce the correct solution.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

**Because this is an electrical site, my solution is based on reducing the circuit to a more manageable form (rather than throwing a pile of equations at it).**

> *How can I calculate the transfer function of this system?*

Here's a hint to get you started: -

[image]

Solve the red block, redraw with a single red block and, merge it with the green block.

Rinse and repeat.

Comment: @pinkcat please read this --> [What should I do when someone answers my question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)